# WPF Command not executed when viewmodel changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and I don't know why binding from the viewmodel does not execute the specified command.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxName" Content="MyCheckBox"  IsChecked="{Binding Restrictions.MyCheckBox}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxName}"/>
```

When I check the checkbox in the view, MyCommand is executed as expected, but when I set the IsChecked property from the viewmodel using binding, the command is not executed.

Does anyone have any idea why it's happening? How can I execute the command from viewmodel using binding?

Thanks you very much!

Comment: Some comments, make the binding `TwoWay`, check if you have implemented `NotifyPropertyChanged` correctly and add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your binding and retest if it works.

Comment: Might not be relevant but can you please try setting `Mode=TwoWay` within the IsChecked Binding?

Comment: Use `CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` and `Name` at this point is not needed. And `CheckBox` uses `TwoWayBinding` by default.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Command is executed on the "Click" event of the base "ButtonBase" class, which is not triggered if you change the IsChecked Property via Binding.
One solution would be to attach a trigger to the Checked and Unchecked event, which triggers your command.

First you need to add the namespace

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

And for your checkbox

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxName" 
          Content="MyCheckBox"  
          IsChecked="{Binding Restrictions.MyCheckBox}" 
          Command="{Binding MyCommand}" 
          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxName}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=CheckBoxName}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=CheckBoxName}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Checkbox>
```